# Extendscript get caller function file path

Tags: javascript, watch, extendscript

I'm trying to get the file path of the caller function. Like in this ex:

Project path: `C:/project/some-project`

index.jsx:

```
#include './test.jsx';
someFunc();
```

test.jsx:

```
function someFunc() {
    return callerFilePath();
}
```

Expected result(one of the following):

- C:/project/some-project/index.jsx
- ./index.js

I tried to add watcher to the $ object like:

```
$.watch('fileName', function(prop, oldval, newval) {
    doSomething();
});
```

But it seems to work only for props that I change and not the core.
Also tried `$.evalFile()`;

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This setup should give you the path to the file where your function is in.

Folder structure:

```
├── index.jsx
└── sub-folder
    └── include.jsx
```

Content of index.jsx

```
//@include "sub-folder/include.jsx"
$.writeln(getPath());
```

Content of include.jsx

```
function getPath (){
  return $.fileName;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have lots of included files, and I don't want to add to each of them the `getPath` function.

Comment: I think then you are out of luck. What do you need there path for?

Comment: That's what I thought.. For logging and for functions that depends on caller path.. I have a solution for my problem, but it will be more difficult. Thanks anyway